# Issue with "Circle" class and Constructor in Java?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, textfield, numberformatexception

Ok, so this is the assignment I'm working on:

"Create a Java project with a graphical user interface that allows a user to select which shape they wish to work with: Square, Rectangle, Circle, Triangle

And they enter the dimensions for the shape and can select to compute the area for the shape.

You are to use a base class "Shape" and then have 4 different classes that inherit from Shape in order to compute the Area.  Your calculation for Area shall use the appropriate class's area() method"

My idea for the GUI was to let the user choose the shape via radio buttons in the same group, then have them enter dimensions (height and width) in respective text fields. After they've done both of those, they'd push a button and the area for the shape would be computed.

My issue is that I've created the base Shape class and four inheriting classes, and I've "connected" them to the main class with the GUI the best I could, but when trying to compute the Circle area I'm getting exceptions because the program wants the user to enter numbers in both the height and width field, when I want the Circle area to just be computed via the width field (Because the formula just requires one dimension). I set up multiple constructors to deal with this, but I've obviously done something wrong. All of the other Shapes are computing just fine.

Here is my main (GUI) code for when the button is pressed:

```
private void buttonAreaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        int height = Integer.parseInt(tfHeight.getText());
        int width = Integer.parseInt(tfWidth.getText());

        try {
            Square mySquare = new Square(height,width);
            Circle myCircle = new Circle(width);
            Triangle myTriangle = new Triangle(height,width);
            Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(height,width);

            double result = 0;

            if (rbSquare.isSelected()) {
                result = mySquare.area();
            }//end of if block
            else if (rbCircle.isSelected()){
                result = myCircle.area();
            }
            else if (rbTriangle.isSelected()){
                result = myTriangle.area();
            }
            else if (rbRectangle.isSelected()){
                result = myRectangle.area();
            }//end of else block

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Area is " + result);
        }//end of try block
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            //Display new window with text upon catching exception
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter the proper dimensions");
        }//end of catch block
    }
```

Here is the base Shape class code:

```
public class Shape extends mainWindow {
    //create properties for class
    int width;
    int height;

    //default constructor to override method
    public Shape(){
        //"this" uses properties above
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }//end of constructor

    //create the constructor (same as the class name) and pass it arguments
    public Shape(int height, int width){
        //"this" uses properties above
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }//end of constructor

    public Shape(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
```

Here is the Circle class Code:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    //constructor
    Circle(int width){
        this.width = width;

    }

    public double area(){
        return Math.PI*(width*width);
    }
}
```

So to reiterate when the user chooses the Circle option and then enters a dimension in width, they get an error. they have to enter the dimension in the height and width box, which isnt what I want (It doesnt actually take the height value and use it to compute, but it's demanding that the height text field be filled)

Can anyone help me figure this out or tell me where I went wrong?

Here is the exception stacktrace:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at bism3800.mainWindow.buttonAreaActionPerformed(mainWindow.java:150)
    at bism3800.mainWindow.access$000(mainWindow.java:14)
    at bism3800.mainWindow$1.actionPerformed(mainWindow.java:71)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Please post your complete exception stacktrace message. This is key to solving your problem and should always be posted in with the question.

Comment: Your subclasses should call the super's constructor within their own constructor.

Comment: Your problem seems to be just where you try to do parseint on your height field.

Comment: I posted the stacktrace message, sorry about that. I don't have a great understanding of classes and constructors because I just learned about them this week, sorry. Can you give me an example (or point me to one) about what that would look like?

Comment: It's demanding `height` because you are getting the `height` at the very beginning of the method, line with `int height...`. You should move it and only use it when you need it in one of your `if` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only doing what you are telling it to do. In the beginning of the listener, you extract the text from **both** text fields and then parse them, and this happens **regardless of which radiobutton has been chosen**:

```
private void buttonAreaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    // this code is **always** run, no matter what
    int height = Integer.parseInt(tfHeight.getText());
    int width = Integer.parseInt(tfWidth.getText());
```

The obvious solution is not to do this. To only parse what is needed, when it is needed, and within the if statements.

Your key problem is that you're not doing a most important debugging step: a mental walk through of your code, to understand what it's doing at every step. Start doing this, now, frequently.

As per the [How to Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Appendices/errorsAndDebug.html) article:

> In order to program, you need to have a mental model of how programs work. If you write a program that doesn’t do what you expect, very often the problem is not in the program; it’s in your mental model.